# Get image src using JQuery from dynamically loaded images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some php code which creates html that displays images by pulling their paths from a database:

```
        $primephoto = ~some path from a database~;
        echo '  
            <div class="widget_photo">
                <img src="'.$primephoto.'">
            </div>';
```

I am trying to get the source of the image I click on using the following code:

```
        $(".widget_photo img").click(function(){ 
            var images = $('.widget_photo img').attr('src');
            alert(images);  
        });
```

But it returns the source of just the first image always.

I think whats going on is that the php code is rendering a bunch of html div's all with the class name "widget_photo", and the JQuery just looks at the first one, grabs the image src and returns that.

But I need the source of the **specific image that is being clicked on**.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get `src` of the current `this` image:

```
$(".widget_photo img").click(function(){ 
    var images = $(this).attr('src');
    alert(images);  
});
```